# MySQL Parse and Split JSON value

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, knex.js, unnest

I have a column which contains a JSON value of different lengths

```
["The Cherries:2.50","Draw:3.25","Swansea Jacks:2.87"]
```

I want to split them and store into a JSON like so:

```
[
  {
    name: "The Cherries",
    odds: 2.50
  },
  {
    name: "Draw",
    odds: 3.25
  },
  {
    name: "Swansea",
    odds: 2.87
  },
]
```

What I did right now is looping and splitting them in the UI which to me is quite heavy for the client. I want to parse and split them all in a single query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `json_table()` to split the original arrayto rows, and then build new objects and aggregate them with `json_arrayagg()`.

We need a primary key column (or set of columns) so we can properly aggreate the generated rows, I assumed `id`:

```
select 
    t.id, 
    json_arrayagg(json_object(
        'name', substring(j.val, 1, locate(':', j.val) - 1), 
        'odds', substring(j.val, locate(':', j.val) + 1)
    )) new_js
from mytable t
cross join json_table(t.js, '$[*]' columns (val varchar(500) path '$')) as j
group by t.id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ff75d4c0b0b023b5ce640e9285cb1b4f)**

Sample data:

```
id | js                                                      
-: | :-------------------------------------------------------
 1 | ["The Cherries:2.50", "Draw:3.25", "Swansea Jacks:2.87"]
```

Query results:

```
id | new_js                                                                                                                 
-: | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | [{"name": "The Cherries", "odds": "2.50"}, {"name": "Draw", "odds": "3.25"}, {"name": "Swansea Jacks", "odds": "2.87"}]
```

Comment: Hi! I just want to ask more about the problem. Right know I'm using a subquery to union all tables. `(SELECT * FROM _bet365_soccer_premier) as t` but it returns an error `Incorrect arguments to JSON_TABLE`. However, if I dont use a subquery, and using only `_bet365_soccer_premier as t`. It works, I don't know why

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw: if I understand your correctly, you need to replace `mytable` with your `union` subquery, like `from (select ... from table1 union all select ... from table2 union all ...) as t cross join json_table(...) as j ...`

Comment: yes, I believe that's what I'm doing. `SELECT 
  logs2.id,
  json_arrayagg(json_object (
      'name',
      SUBSTRING(j.val, 1, LOCATE(':', j.val) - 1),
      'odds',
      SUBSTRING(j.val, LOCATE(':', j.val) + 1)
    )) new_js 
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM _bet365_soccer_premier UNION ALL SELECT * FROM _bet365_hose_victoria) AS logs2
  CROSS JOIN json_table(logs2.odds,'$[*]' COLUMNS (val VARCHAR (500) path '$')) AS j 
GROUP BY logs2.id `

Comment: ahh nvm, thank you! I don't know where I got wrong but the same query doesn't work before, maybe I've ran the wrong query.

Comment: @GMD, I've caught the problem. It doesn't work if only single table is passed. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5ed81bea48fe7d5688109e02fdae2dc9

Answer (score 1):

You can use json_table to create rows from the json object.
Just replace table_name with your table name and json with the column that contains json

---

```
 SELECT json_arrayagg(json_object('name',SUBSTRING_INDEX(person, ':', 1) ,'odds',SUBSTRING_INDEX(person, ':', -1) )) 
 FROM table_name,
 JSON_TABLE(json, '$[*]' COLUMNS (person VARCHAR(40) PATH '$') people;
```

Here is a Db fiddle you can refer

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=801de9f067e89a48d45ef9a5bd2d094a

Comment: Thank you! But I wonder how to use this. Say, my table name is `table_name` and the JSON column would be `odds`?

Comment: json would be the column that contains json value in your table.

Comment: It does not seem to work. 

`SELECT json_arrayagg(json_object('name',SUBSTRING_INDEX(person, ':', 1) ,'odds',SUBSTRING_INDEX(person, ':', -1) )) 
 FROM _bet365_soccer_premier AS table_name,
 JSON_TABLE(table_name.odds, '$[*]' COLUMNS (person VARCHAR(40) PATH '$') people;`

Comment: creating a db fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=801de9f067e89a48d45ef9a5bd2d094a